# How can I access td Id in aspx.cs page of asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used this code but it doesn't work.

```
HtmlGenericControl T1 = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("T1");
T1.Visible = false;
```

Error Is:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: Well does the control exist on the page? Does it have an ID of `T1`? My guess is *probably not*.

Comment: Please add the ASP code

Comment: Well where is the relevant markup ?

Comment: You should probably check that `T1` is not null before using it as well as adding the `runat=server` code.

Answer (score 5):

add `runat="server"` and id to TD

```
<td runat="server" id="tdToSelect">
```

now you can set

```
tdToSelect.visible = false;
```

If this is inside update panel use [`UpdatePanel.FindControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.findcontrol.aspx) method

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat='server'` to your `td`. Otherwise you'll need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

What you *can* do, is use ASP.NET's `TableRow` and `TableCell` controls instead of HTML's `<TR>` and `<TD>` elements. You can then access the control you need from your ASP.NET code behind.

At render time, those controls will of course emit `<TR>` and `<TD>` elements, but you will know the ID to use in your server-side code and your code can modify the control before the server sends the generated HTML to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reference server side controls from your C# code. i.e. you should have an attribute set to your control  runat=server and you can then assign an id to it. This way, you will be able to access it from your c# code.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that FindControl function not make recursive search but you can add `runat="server"` to your TD and set visible.